# Unhandled Exception : type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter

I am currently building an signup app to post data to an api.

I made a model class for Users(user.dart)

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String phone;
  final String password;

  User({this.id, this.name, this.email, this.phone, this.password});
  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      email: json['email'],
      phone: json['phone'],
      password: json['password'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "phone": phone,
        "password": password,
      };

  Map toMap() {
    var map = new Map();
    map["name"] = name;
    map["email"] = email;
    map["phone"] = phone;
    map["password"] = password;
    map["hides"] = "xxxxx";
    return map;
  }
}
```

This is signup.dart to post data on api

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

//post method
Future addUser({Map body}) async {
  String signup_url = 'https://www.xxxxxxxxx/apiregister.php';
  return await http
      .post(
    signup_url,
    body: jsonEncode(body),
  )
      .then(
    (http.Response response) {
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
      print(statusCode);
      print(response.body);

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
        throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));   //error is occuring here
    },
  );
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _key = new GlobalKey();
  String name, email, phone, password;
  bool visible = true;
  final TextEditingController _nameController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _phoneController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (this.mounted) super.dispose();
    _nameController.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _phoneController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Form(
              key: _key,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: size.height * 0.078,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'SignUp Page',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: validateUsername,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _nameController,
                        hintText: 'Name',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: kPrimaryColor,
                        ),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                      onSaved: (String value) {
                        name = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: validateEmail,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      controller: _emailController,
                        hintText: 'Email',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: kPrimaryColor,
                        ),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                      onSaved: (String value) {
                        email = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: validateMobile,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                      controller: _phoneController,
                        hintText: 'Phone',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: kPrimaryColor,
                        ),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                      onSaved: (String value) {
                        phone = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: validatePassword,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      controller: _passwordController,
                      obscureText: visible,
                        suffix: InkWell(
                          child: visible
                              ? Icon(
                                  Icons.visibility_off,
                                  size: 20,
                                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                                )
                              : Icon(
                                  Icons.visibility,
                                  size: 20,
                                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                                ),
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(
                              () {
                                visible = !visible;
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Password',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: kPrimaryColor,
                        ),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                      onSaved: (String value) {
                        password = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
                            print("Successful");
                            User newuser = new User(
                                id: "0",
                                name: _nameController.text,
                                email: _emailController.text,
                                phone: _phoneController.text,
                                password: _passwordController.text);
                            User u = await addUser(body: newuser.toMap());
                            print(u.id);
                            print(u.name);
                            print(u.email);
                            print(u.phone);
                            print(u.password);
                          } else {
                            print("UnSuccessful");
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'SIGNUP',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error that I am currently running into is :
`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

i tried resolving it using a cast:

```
User(
  id: json['id'].cast<String>(),
  name: json['name'].cast<String>(),
  email: json['email'].cast<String>(),
  phone: json['phone'].cast<String>(),
  password: json['password'].cast<String>(),
);
```

but it didn't work so please help me to get it solved.

How do I rectify this error?

Comment: please share your json response and try   User.fromJson(response.body)

Comment: problem would be your server is returning you the list of maps. Please try to share your response.

Comment: i tried to print the json response  as => String jsonresponse = response.body and  print(jsonresponse), then the output comes as ["error"]